# Move question to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, migration

I originally posted a question on Programmers because at the time it was quite general with no code.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195959/java-blocking-on-multiple-queues

After doing some work on the problem I have a fair amount of actual code which I added to the question.  Now it looks more like a question about a specific problem I'm having, ie it's now more suited to Stack Overflow than Programmers.

I've voted to migrate the question to SO, but I can't migrate it until others vote to migrate it as well.

If you agree and think it's better for Stack Overflow in its current form can you please vote to migrate it?

Answer (score 3):

While there is nothing wrong with it, you don't need to post a meta question requesting the community migrate your question if you feel it is in the wrong place.

You have the ability to Flag for a moderator's attention and give your request directly to us where we can make a determination on what the most appropriate action is.

I went ahead and migrated it for you.

Comment: Thanks.  Like I said, I think it started out okay for here but with edits it became more of an SO question.