# Popular question closed instead of migrated

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration, locked-question

I've flagged my [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44929/color-schemes-generation-theory-and-algorithms) and asked for it to be moved to Stack Overflow ([that's the right way of doing it, right?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5874/move-question-to-stack-overflow)) but it was closed instead. I think it's a good question ([not a crap](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3887/closed-instead-of-migrated)) that proved to be relevant to many people over the years.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Questions older than 60 days can no longer be migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days), not even by moderators.

Your question, albeit being off topic on both Programmers and Stack Overflow, is fairly popular and generated a few very useful answers. This, I assume, is why Thomas decided to place a historical lock on it. The lock will prevent it from being deleted by the community, which is what usually happens to off topic questions after a while.

Comment: just out of curiosity, if the question is not a fit for Programmers nor SO where could it fit? Thanks

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek I'd really wish there was a SE site where your question could find a better home, but I don't think there is one. There's nothing inherently wrong with the specific question, the problem is that the Q&A format doesn't really cope with broad recommendation questions. The good ones _may_ generate a few helpful answers, but the bad ones almost always end up being a total crapfest. And, unfortunately, every time we are being a bit lenient with a good one, hundreds of similar lesser quality ones appear and spoil the fun for everyone.

Comment: I think the question _could_ be a fit for Programmers with some editing. Specifically, by stating what algorithm you are trying to use, what you had success or failure with, and ask for guidance. Essentially, a review of your algorithm design. As it was asked, the question sounds more like you are punting to the community which rarely elicits positive responses. Thankfully for you, you received useful information in this case.